# How to elegantly transform '1-3,6-8' to '1 2 3 6 7 8' within a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.5

## Problem

**Background:**

I have a list of ~10,000 lists containing irregular data which needs to be transformed to a specific format. This data will be ingested into a pandas dataframe after transformation.

**TL/DR;** How to elegantly transform matched strings of the following regex in a list?

**Regex**
'\d{1,3}-\d{1,3},\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}'

**Example:**
'1-3,6-8' to '1 2 3 6 7 8'

**Current Solution:**
Using list comprehensions required multiple type casts to transform the string and is unfit to be a lasting solution.

```
pat = re.compile('\d{1,3}-\d{1,3},\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}')

row = ['sss-www,ddd-eee', '1-3,6-8', 'XXXX', '0-2,3-7','234','1,5']

lst = [((str(list(range(int(x.split(',')[0].split('-')[0]), 
    int(x.split(','[0].split('-')[1])+1))).strip('[]').replace(',', '')+' '
    +str(list(range(int(x.split(',')[1].split('-')[0]), 
    int(x.split(',')[1].split('-')[1]) + 1))).strip('[]').replace(',', ''))) 
    if pat.match(str(x)) else x for x in row]
```

**Result**

```
    ['sss-www,ddd-eee', '1 2 3 6 7 8', 'XXXX', '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7', '234', '1,5']
```

Comment: Are you familiar with regular expression capturing groups? There is no need to use `split`

Comment: Break this down into smaller problems. You're asking the wrong question, and don't actually need regex to do this at all.

Comment: Bryan, I'm not intimately familiar with them but I think I just read enough on them to understand how you could process this without using split()

Comment: jonrsharpe, I'm using the regex to identify the case for processing within irregular data. How could the case be identified without regex?

Answer (score 1):

Capture the groups it's easier.

Then you convert the group list to integers, and process them 2 by 2 in a list comprehension, chained with `itertools.chain`

```
import re,itertools

pat = re.compile('(\d{1,3})-(\d{1,3}),(\d{1,3})-(\d{1,3})')

z='1-3,6-8'

groups = [int(x) for x in pat.match(z).groups()]

print(list(itertools.chain(*(list(range(groups[i],groups[i+1]+1)) for i in range(0,len(groups),2)))))
```

result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8]
```

not sure you're calling that "elegant", though. It remains complicated, mostly because most objects return generators that need converting to `list` explicitly.

Comment: Not that it makes it more elegant but, both `list(...)` calls can be replaced by unpacking instead: `print(*(chain(*(range(groups[i],groups[i+1]+1) for i in range(0,len(groups),2)))))`

Answer (score 1):

Several ways to do this, here is mine:

```
import re

txt =  '1-3,6-8'

# Safer to use a raw string
pat  = re.compile(r'(\d{1,3})-(\d{1,3}),(\d{1,3})-(\d{1,3})')
m = pat.match(txt)
if m:
    start1, end1, start2, end2 = m.groups()
    result  = [i for i in range(int(start1), int(end1)+1)]
    result += [i for i in range(int(start2), int(end2)+1)]
    print(result)
```

Gives:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8]
```

I'm assuming Python 3 here (as stated in the question).

Python 2 could use:

```
result  = range(int(start1), int(end1)+1)   
result += range(int(start2), int(end2)+1)
```

Comment: Python 3 can do that too.  `result = list(range(...))` and `result += range(...)` both work fine in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to handle longer sequences as well, like `1-10,15,23-25`?  You don't really need regular expressions for this, regular string processing functions will work well.

```
def parse_sequence(seq):
    result = []
    for part in seq.split(','):
        points = [int(s) for s in part.split('-')]
        if len(points) == 2:
            result.extend(range(points[0], points[1]+1))
        elif len(points) == 1:
            result.append(points[0])
        else:
            raise ValueError('invalid sequence')
    return result
```

Comment: yes, I'd like to handle the extension case.
I'm using the regex in the beginning to identify the data that would be submitted to the function. I have a list of ~10,000 lists that contain various data, and this specific data needs to be transformed in place as it's only one of many cases I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on exactly what data you're expecting to see. In general the best way to do this is going to be to write a function that parses the string in chunks. Something like:

```
def parse(string):
    chunks = string.split(',')
    for chunk in chunks:
        match = re.match('(\d+)-(\d+)', chunk)
        if match:
            start = int(match.group(1))
            end = int(match.group(2))
            yield range(start:end+1)
        else:
            yield int(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
import re
from itertools import chain

s = '1-3, 6 - 8, 12-14, 20 -22'

rslt = list(chain(*[range(int(tup[0]), int(tup[1]) + 1)
                    for tup in re.findall(r'(\d+)\s*?-\s*?(\d+)', s)]))
```

Output:

```
In [43]: rslt
Out[43]: [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14, 20, 21, 22]
```

Step by step:

```
In [44]: re.findall(r'(\d+)\s*?-\s*?(\d+)', s)
Out[44]: [('1', '3'), ('6', '8'), ('12', '14'), ('20', '22')]

In [45]: [range(int(tup[0]),int(tup[1])+1) for tup in re.findall(r'(\d+)\s*?-\s*?(\d+)', s)]
Out[45]: [range(1, 4), range(6, 9), range(12, 15), range(20, 23)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s_tmp = s.split(",")

[*range(x.split("-")int([0]),x.split("-")int(x[1])) for x in s_tmp]
```

apologies if there is syntax errors . i'm typing this from my phone . basically split by , then split by - then unpack the entries from range